# What exactly does cleanAllSessions() does?

Tags: magento-1.9, session

I came accross a line `Mage::app()->cleanAllSessions();` and going through the function I saw that it fetches the session save path and deletes it. i havent specified any `session_save_path` in my `local.xml` and have all my sessions saving in files, when i run this code it doesnt really clears the `var/session` folder, so what does it do actually?

FYI, calling `session_save_path()` returns `c:\xampp\tmp`.

Comment: How about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `session_save_path` returns the path of the current directory used to save session data. We can set the path for it, ex: `session_save_path('var/session')`. If we didn't set any path value, the session data will store in the `tmp` folder of our web service. This is reason why when calling `session_save_path()`, it returns `c:\xampp\tmp` in your case.

Look into this file:

*downloader/Maged/Controller.php*

```
protected function cleanCache()
{
    ......     
    Mage::app()->cleanAllSessions();
    ......             

}
```

As we can see,`Mage::app()->cleanAllSessions()` is used for updating process. And, we don't set any value for `session_save_path` in this process, so, the `tmp` folder will store the session data. After updating successfully, we need to clear these values.

Now, we should find the session path of our Magento website.

Navigate to the core model session files:

*app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php*

```
public function getSessionSavePath()
{
        if (Mage::isInstalled() && $sessionSavePath = Mage::getConfig()->getNode(self::XML_NODE_SESSION_SAVE_PATH)) {
            return $sessionSavePath;
        }
        return parent::getSessionSavePath();
}
```

*app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php*

```
public function getSessionSavePath()
{
    return Mage::getBaseDir('session');
}
```

The session save path will be set if we have set this value in `app/etc/local.xml`. If not, it gets the path from `Mage::getBaseDir('session')` -> `var/session` will be used.

Try with an example:

*app/etc/local.xml*

```
<global>
    ......
    <session_save_path><![CDATA[var/store_session]]></session_save_path>
    ......
</global>
```

Print out the value:

*app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php*

```
public function getSessionSavePath()
{
        if (Mage::isInstalled() && $sessionSavePath = Mage::getConfig()->getNode(self::XML_NODE_SESSION_SAVE_PATH)) {
            var_dump($sessionSavePath);
            die;
            return $sessionSavePath;
        }
        return parent::getSessionSavePath();
}
```

> object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)#26 (1) { [0]=> string(17)
>   "var/store_session" }

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You initially said that if we dont have the session_save_path value et then it uses tmp folder of the webservice and then later again you have menioned that it uses var/session folder. I am a bit confused here. Also what session value does it save on updating a process like clearning cache for that matter. I monitored the tmp as well var/session folder, cleanAllSessions() doesnt seem to clean anything.

Comment: `cleanAllSessions()` -> is used for the updating process. The `normal` session of our Magento site will be stored under `var/session` folder as default. Look into the core session Magento, Magento will check and get the session path from  `app/etc/local.xml` config.  If not, it gets the path from `Mage::getBaseDir('session')` ->`var/session` will be used.

Comment: You should create `var/store_session` and declare it in `app/etc/local.xml`: `<session_save_path><![CDATA[var/store_session]]></session_sa‌​ve_path>`. You will see what happens.

Comment: Your answers are contradictory..is session_save_path and getSessionSavePath the same thing?